# Can't make one valid view from multiple tables , i have data duplication problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I have to unite more than 12 tables value in one view and I should make it with the help of view. Here are two selects which show us what kind of data I should have in a view, I have tried view's several combination but nothing of them were helpful, they provide too many duplicates.

What should I do to get rid of these duplicates?

Here are my two selects and my views example.

First table

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ,ISNULL(SoxInf.InformationGUID,'') AS EntryGuid
    ,ISNULL([Entry].EntryGUID,'')  AS LineGuid
    ,ISNULL([Entry].LineNumber,0) AS LineNum
    ,ISNULL([Entry].productID,0) AS Productid
    ,ISNULL([Entry].ProductName,'') AS ProductNum
    ,ISNULL([Entry].CommercialDescription,'') AS ProductDesc
    ,ISNULL([Entry].Brand,'') AS StyleNum
    ,ISNULL([Entry].TaxIDOfManufacturer,'') AS ManufacturerID
    ,ISNULL([Entry].ManufacturerInfo,'') AS ManufacturerName
    ,ISNULL([Entry].GrossWeight,0) AS GrossWeight
    ,ISNULL([Entry].NetWeight,0) AS NetWeight
    ,ISNULL([Entry].NumberOfUnits,0) AS TxnQty
    ,ISNULL([Entry].TypeOfUnits,'') AS TxnQtyUOM
    ,ISNULL([Entry].SumValue,0) AS TotalValue
    ,ISNULL([Entry].StatisticalAmount,0) AS RptQty
    ,ISNULL(TaxInsurence.Rate,0) AS ExactRate
    ,ISNULL(TaxInsurence.Amount,0) AS Duty
    ,ISNULL(TaxInsurence.Amount,0) + ISNULL(Calculate.AddlDuty,0) AS TotalDuty
    ,ISNULL(BorderTax.Amount,0) AS TotalBorderTaxValue
    ,ISNULL(CustomerTax.Amount,0) AS TotalCustomerTaxValue
    ,ISNULL(OtherTax.Amount,0) AS TotalOtherTaxValue
    ,ISNULL(SoxInf.CountryOfDeparture,0) AS ExportCountry 
    ,ISNULL(SoxInf.Term,'') AS Terms
    ,ISNULL(SoxInf.RelationshipOfBuyerAndSeller,'') AS RelatedPartyFlag 
    ,LocalPortExpenses + OtherLocalExpenses + FreightAmount + InsuranceAmount + TresspassingFeeAtTheBorder AS Fees
    ,ISNULL(TotalCalculate.TotalAVeragePayments,0) AS TotalSummedPayments
FROM 
    [Incoming] Incoming 
LEFT JOIN 
    [Documentinformation] SoxInf ON SoxInf.IncomingGUID = Incoming.IncomingGUID 
                                 AND SoxInf.PartnerId = Incoming.PartnerId
LEFT JOIN 
    [IncomingDocuments] Document ON Document.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
LEFT JOIN 
    [IncomingEntryDocument] [Entry] ON [Entry].InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         SoxInf.InformationGUID AS DocumentExtraInformationGUID
         ,SoxInf.PartnerId AS PartnerId
         ,(SoxInf.CounterveilingDuty * (ISNULL([Entry].SumValue,0) / ISNULL(NULLIF(EntrySum.SumSumValue,0),1))) AS AddlDuty
     FROM 
         [Documentinformation] SoxInf 
     LEFT JOIN 
         [IncomingEntryDocument] [Entry] ON [Entry].InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
                                         AND 
     LEFT JOIN 
         (SELECT 
              DocumentExtraInformationGUID, SUM(SumValue) AS SumSumValue
          FROM 
              [IncomingEntryDocument] 
          GROUP BY 
              DocumentExtraInformationGUID) EntrySum ON EntrySum.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
     GROUP BY 
         SoxInf.DocumentExtraInformationGUID
        ,SoxInf.PartnerId
        ,SoxInf.CounterveilingDuty
        ,[Entry].SumValue
        ,EntrySum.SumSumValue) Calculate ON Calculate.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
                                         AND 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         SoxInf.InformationGUID AS DocumentExtraInformationGUID
        ,(ISNULL(TaxInsurence.Amount,0) + (SoxInf.CounterveilingDuty * (ISNULL([Entry].SumValue,0) / ISNULL(NULLIF(EntrySum.SumSumValue,0),1))) 
          + ISNULL(BorderTax.Amount,0) + ISNULL(CustomerTax.Amount,0) + ISNULL(OtherTax.Amount,0)
          + ISNULL([Entry].LocalPortExpenses,0) + ISNULL([Entry].OtherLocalExpenses,0)
          + ISNULL([Entry].FreightAmount,0) + ISNULL([Entry].InsuranceAmount,0)
          + ISNULL([Entry].TresspassingFeeAtTheBorder,0)) AS TotalAVeragePayments
    FROM [Documentinformation] SoxInf 
    LEFT JOIN [IncomingEntryDocument] [Entry] 
    ON [Entry].InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID AND [Entry].PartnerID = SoxInf.PartnerId
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DocumentExtraInformationGUID, PartnerID, SUM(SumValue) AS SumSumValue
        FROM [IncomingEntryDocument] 
        GROUP BY DocumentExtraInformationGUID, PartnerID) EntrySum
    ON EntrySum.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
    LEFT JOIN [EntryTaxInformation] TaxInsurence 
    ON TaxInsurence.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
        AND TaxInsurence.Code = '10'
    LEFT JOIN [EntryTaxInformation] BorderTax 
    ON BorderTax.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
        AND BorderTax.Code = '40'
    LEFT JOIN [EntryTaxInformation] CustomerTax 
    ON CustomerTax.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
    LEFT JOIN [EntryTaxInformation] OtherTax 
    ON OtherTax.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID
        AND OtherTax.Code = '89'
    GROUP BY SoxInf.DocumentExtraInformationGUID
        ,TaxInsurence.Amount
        ,BorderTax.Amount
        ,CustomerTax.Amount
        ,OtherTax.Amount
        ,SoxInf.CounterveilingDuty
        ,[Entry].SumValue
        ,EntrySum.SumSumValue
        ,[Entry].LocalPortExpenses
        ,[Entry].OtherLocalExpenses
        ,[Entry].FreightAmount
        ,[Entry].InsuranceAmount
        ,[Entry].TresspassingFeeAtTheBorder
    ) TotalCalculate
ON TotalCalculate.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
LEFT JOIN EntryTaxInformation TaxInsurence 
ON TaxInsurence.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
    AND TaxInsurence.Code = '10'
LEFT JOIN [EntryTaxInformation] BorderTax 
ON BorderTax.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
    AND BorderTax.Code = '40'
LEFT JOIN [EntryTaxInformation] CustomerTax 
ON CustomerTax.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
    AND CustomerTax.Code = '93'
LEFT JOIN [EntryTaxInformation] OtherTax 
ON OtherTax.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
    AND OtherTax.Code = '89'
```

Second Table

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                     ISNULL(Inf.InformationGUID,'') AS EntryRecordGuid
                    ,ISNULL(Inf.RegistryNumber,'') AS Num
                    ,ISNULL(Inf.TaxIDOfTheDeclarant,'') AS BrokerID 
                    ,ISNULL(Inf.TypeOfDocument,'')  AS DocumentType
                    ,ISNULL(Inf.CustomerId,'') AS CustomerID
                    ,ISNULL(Inf.RelatedReference,'') AS ReferenceNum
                    ,CONVERT(DATETIME,(SELECT MAX(ISNULL(Document.DocumentDate,'')) FROM [EntryRecordDocument] Document 
                        WHERE Document.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                        GROUP BY Document.InformationGUID),104) AS Registration
                    ,CONVERT(DATETIME,(SELECT MAX(ISNULL(Document.DocumentDate,'')) FROM [EntryRecordDocument] Document 
                        WHERE Document.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                        GROUP BY Document.InformationGUID),104) AS Eidt 
                    ,CONVERT(DATETIME,(SELECT MAX(ISNULL(Document.ApprovalDate,'')) FROM [EntryRecordDocument] Document 
                        WHERE Document.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                        GROUP BY Document.InformationGUID),104) AS ReleaseDate  
                    ,ISNULL(Inf.TypeOfVehicleAtTheBorder,'') AS ModeOfTransport
                    ,CONVERT(varchar(6),FLOOR(ISNULL([EntryRecord].LocalPort,0))) AS PortOfFiling
                    ,SUM(DutyCalculate.Duty) AS TotalPaymentValue
                    ,SUM(LocalPortExpenses + OtherLocalExpenses + FreightAmount + InsuranceAmount + TresspassingFeeAtTheBorder) AS TotalFees
                    ,SUM(DeclarationPaymentsCalculate.DeclarationPayments) AS TotalDeclarationPayments
                FROM [Incoming] Incoming 
                LEFT JOIN [Documentinformation] Inf 
                ON Inf.IncomingGUID = Incoming.IncomingGUID 
                LEFT JOIN [EntryRecordInformation] [EntryRecord] 
                ON [EntryRecord].InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT Inf.InformationGUID AS InformationGUID
                        ,(ISNULL(Tax.Amount,0) + (Inf.CounterveilingDuty * (ISNULL([EntryRecord].StatisticValue,0) / ISNULL(NULLIF(EntryRecordSum.SumStatisticValue,0),1)))) AS Duty
                    FROM [Documentinformation] Inf 
                    LEFT JOIN [EntryRecordInformation] [EntryRecord] 
                    ON [EntryRecord].InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                    LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT InformationGUID, PartnerID, SUM(StatisticValue) AS SumStatisticValue
                        FROM [EntryRecordInformation] 
                        GROUP BY InformationGUID, PartnerID) EntryRecordSum
                        ON EntryRecordSum.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                        LEFT JOIN [EntryRecordTax] Tax 
                        ON Tax.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                            AND Tax.Code = '10'
                        GROUP BY Inf.InformationGUID
                            ,Tax.Amount
                            ,Inf.CounterveilingDuty
                            ,[EntryRecord].StatisticValue
                            ,EntryRecordSum.SumStatisticValue
                    ) DutyCalculate
                ON DutyCalculate.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                LEFT JOIN(
                    SELECT Inf.InformationGUID AS InformationGUID
                        ,(ISNULL(TaxInsurence.Amount,0) + (Inf.CounterveilingDuty * (ISNULL([EntryRecord].StatisticValue,0) / ISNULL(NULLIF(EntryRecordSum.SumStatisticValue,0),1))) 
                          + ISNULL(BorderTax.Amount,0) + ISNULL(CustomerTax.Amount,0) + ISNULL(OtherTax.Amount,0)
                          + ISNULL([EntryRecord].LocalPortExpenses,0) + ISNULL([EntryRecord].OtherLocalExpenses,0)
                          + ISNULL([EntryRecord].FreightAmount,0) + ISNULL([EntryRecord].InsuranceAmount,0)
                          + ISNULL([EntryRecord].TresspassingFeeAtTheBorder,0)) AS DeclarationPayments
                    FROM [Documentinformation] Inf 
                    LEFT JOIN [EntryRecordInformation] [EntryRecord] 
                    ON [EntryRecord].InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID AND [EntryRecord].PartnerID = Inf.PartnerId
                    LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT InformationGUID, PartnerID, SUM(StatisticValue) AS SumStatisticValue
                        FROM [EntryRecordInformation] 
                        GROUP BY InformationGUID, PartnerID) EntryRecordSum
                    ON EntryRecordSum.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                    LEFT JOIN [EntryRecordTax] TaxInsurence 
                    ON TaxInsurence.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID
                        AND TaxInsurence.Code = '10'
                    LEFT JOIN [EntryRecordTax] BorderTax 
                    ON BorderTax.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                        AND BorderTax.Code = '40'
                    LEFT JOIN [EntryRecordTax] CustomerTax 
                    ON CustomerTax.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                        AND CustomerTax.Code = '93'
                    LEFT JOIN [EntryRecordTax] OtherTax 
                    ON OtherTax.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                        AND OtherTax.Code = '89'
                    GROUP BY Inf.InformationGUID
                        ,TaxInsurence.Amount
                        ,BorderTax.Amount
                        ,CustomerTax.Amount
                        ,OtherTax.Amount
                        ,Inf.CounterveilingDuty
                        ,[EntryRecord].StatisticValue
                        ,EntryRecordSum.SumStatisticValue
                        ,[EntryRecord].LocalPortExpenses
                        ,[EntryRecord].OtherLocalExpenses
                        ,[EntryRecord].FreightAmount
                        ,[EntryRecord].InsuranceAmount
                        ,[EntryRecord].TresspassingFeeAtTheBorder
                    ) DeclarationPaymentsCalculate
                ON DeclarationPaymentsCalculate.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID  
                GROUP BY Inf.InformationGUID
                    ,Inf.RegistryNumber
                    ,Inf.TaxIDOfTheDeclarant
                    ,Inf.TypeOfDocument
                    ,Inf.CustomerId
                    ,Inf.RelatedReference
                    ,Inf.TypeOfVehicleAtTheBorder
```

My view

```
CREATE VIEW
AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
,ISNULL(SoxInf.InformationGUID,'') AS EntryGuid
    ,ISNULL([Entry].EntryGUID,'')  AS LineGuid
    ,ISNULL([Entry].LineNumber,0) AS LineNum
    ,ISNULL([Entry].productID,0) AS Productid
    ,ISNULL([Entry].ProductName,'') AS ProductNum
    ,ISNULL([Entry].CommercialDescription,'') AS ProductDesc
    ,ISNULL([Entry].Brand,'') AS StyleNum
    ,ISNULL([Entry].TaxIDOfManufacturer,'') AS ManufacturerID
    ,ISNULL([Entry].ManufacturerInfo,'') AS ManufacturerName
    ,ISNULL([Entry].GrossWeight,0) AS GrossWeight
    ,ISNULL([Entry].NetWeight,0) AS NetWeight
    ,ISNULL([Entry].NumberOfUnits,0) AS TxnQty
    ,ISNULL([Entry].TypeOfUnits,'') AS TxnQtyUOM
    ,ISNULL([Entry].SumValue,0) AS TotalValue
    ,ISNULL([Entry].StatisticalAmount,0) AS RptQty
    ,ISNULL(TaxInsurence.Rate,0) AS ExactRate
    ,ISNULL(TaxInsurence.Amount,0) AS Duty
    ,ISNULL(TaxInsurence.Amount,0) + ISNULL(Calculate.AddlDuty,0) AS TotalDuty
    ,ISNULL(BorderTax.Amount,0) AS TotalBorderTaxValue
    ,ISNULL(CustomerTax.Amount,0) AS TotalCustomerTaxValue
    ,ISNULL(OtherTax.Amount,0) AS TotalOtherTaxValue
    ,ISNULL(SoxInf.CountryOfDeparture,0) AS ExportCountry 
    ,ISNULL(SoxInf.Term,'') AS Terms
    ,ISNULL(SoxInf.RelationshipOfBuyerAndSeller,'') AS RelatedPartyFlag 
    ,LocalPortExpenses + OtherLocalExpenses + FreightAmount + InsuranceAmount + TresspassingFeeAtTheBorder AS Fees
    ,ISNULL(TotalCalculate.TotalAVeragePayments,0) AS TotalSummedPayments
     ,ISNULL(Inf.InformationGUID,'') AS EntryRecordGuid
                    ,ISNULL(Inf.RegistryNumber,'') AS Num
                    ,ISNULL(Inf.TaxIDOfTheDeclarant,'') AS BrokerID 
                    ,ISNULL(Inf.TypeOfDocument,'')  AS DocumentType
                    ,ISNULL(Inf.CustomerId,'') AS CustomerID
                    ,ISNULL(Inf.RelatedReference,'') AS ReferenceNum
                    ,CONVERT(DATETIME,(SELECT MAX(ISNULL(Document.DocumentDate,'')) FROM [EntryRecordDocument] Document 
                        WHERE Document.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                        GROUP BY Document.InformationGUID),104) AS Registration
                    ,CONVERT(DATETIME,(SELECT MAX(ISNULL(Document.DocumentDate,'')) FROM [EntryRecordDocument] Document 
                        WHERE Document.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                        GROUP BY Document.InformationGUID),104) AS Eidt 
                    ,CONVERT(DATETIME,(SELECT MAX(ISNULL(Document.ApprovalDate,'')) FROM [EntryRecordDocument] Document 
                        WHERE Document.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                        GROUP BY Document.InformationGUID),104) AS ReleaseDate  
                    ,ISNULL(Inf.TypeOfVehicleAtTheBorder,'') AS ModeOfTransport
                    ,CONVERT(varchar(6),FLOOR(ISNULL([EntryRecord].LocalPort,0))) AS PortOfFiling
                    ,SUM(DutyCalculate.Duty) AS TotalPaymentValue
                    ,SUM(LocalPortExpenses + OtherLocalExpenses + FreightAmount + InsuranceAmount + TresspassingFeeAtTheBorder) AS TotalFees
                    ,SUM(DeclarationPaymentsCalculate.DeclarationPayments) AS TotalDeclarationPayments
                    FROM [Incoming] Incoming 
                LEFT JOIN [Documentinformation] Inf 
                ON Inf.IncomingGUID = Incoming.IncomingGUID 
                LEFT JOIN [EntryRecordInformation] [EntryRecord] 
                ON [EntryRecord].InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                --join from another table--
                LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SoxInf.InformationGUID AS DocumentExtraInformationGUID
        ,SoxInf.PartnerId AS PartnerId
        ,(SoxInf.CounterveilingDuty * (ISNULL([Entry].SumValue,0) / ISNULL(NULLIF(EntrySum.SumSumValue,0),1))) AS AddlDuty
    FROM [Documentinformation] SoxInf 
    LEFT JOIN [IncomingEntryDocument] [Entry] 
    ON [Entry].InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID AND 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DocumentExtraInformationGUID, SUM(SumValue) AS SumSumValue
        FROM [IncomingEntryDocument] 
        GROUP BY DocumentExtraInformationGUID) EntrySum
    ON EntrySum.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
    GROUP BY SoxInf.DocumentExtraInformationGUID
        ,SoxInf.PartnerId
        ,SoxInf.CounterveilingDuty
        ,[Entry].SumValue
        ,EntrySum.SumSumValue
    ) Calculate
ON Calculate.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID AND 
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT SoxInf.InformationGUID AS DocumentExtraInformationGUID
        ,(ISNULL(TaxInsurence.Amount,0) + (SoxInf.CounterveilingDuty * (ISNULL([Entry].SumValue,0) / ISNULL(NULLIF(EntrySum.SumSumValue,0),1))) 
          + ISNULL(BorderTax.Amount,0) + ISNULL(CustomerTax.Amount,0) + ISNULL(OtherTax.Amount,0)
          + ISNULL([Entry].LocalPortExpenses,0) + ISNULL([Entry].OtherLocalExpenses,0)
          + ISNULL([Entry].FreightAmount,0) + ISNULL([Entry].InsuranceAmount,0)
          + ISNULL([Entry].TresspassingFeeAtTheBorder,0)) AS TotalAVeragePayments
    FROM [Documentinformation] SoxInf 
    LEFT JOIN [IncomingEntryDocument] [Entry] 
    ON [Entry].InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID AND [Entry].PartnerID = SoxInf.PartnerId
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DocumentExtraInformationGUID, PartnerID, SUM(SumValue) AS SumSumValue
        FROM [IncomingEntryDocument] 
        GROUP BY DocumentExtraInformationGUID, PartnerID) EntrySum
    ON EntrySum.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
    LEFT JOIN [EntryTaxInformation] TaxInsurence 
    ON TaxInsurence.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
        AND TaxInsurence.Code = '10'
    LEFT JOIN [EntryTaxInformation] BorderTax 
    ON BorderTax.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
        AND BorderTax.Code = '40'
    LEFT JOIN [EntryTaxInformation] CustomerTax 
    ON CustomerTax.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
    LEFT JOIN [EntryTaxInformation] OtherTax 
    ON OtherTax.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID
        AND OtherTax.Code = '89'
    GROUP BY SoxInf.DocumentExtraInformationGUID
        ,TaxInsurence.Amount
        ,BorderTax.Amount
        ,CustomerTax.Amount
        ,OtherTax.Amount
        ,SoxInf.CounterveilingDuty
        ,[Entry].SumValue
        ,EntrySum.SumSumValue
        ,[Entry].LocalPortExpenses
        ,[Entry].OtherLocalExpenses
        ,[Entry].FreightAmount
        ,[Entry].InsuranceAmount
        ,[Entry].TresspassingFeeAtTheBorder
    ) TotalCalculate
ON TotalCalculate.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
LEFT JOIN EntryTaxInformation TaxInsurence 
ON TaxInsurence.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
    AND TaxInsurence.Code = '10'
LEFT JOIN [EntryTaxInformation] BorderTax 
ON BorderTax.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
    AND BorderTax.Code = '40'
LEFT JOIN [EntryTaxInformation] CustomerTax 
ON CustomerTax.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
    AND CustomerTax.Code = '93'
LEFT JOIN [EntryTaxInformation] OtherTax 
ON OtherTax.InformationGUID = SoxInf.InformationGUID 
    AND OtherTax.Code = '89'
--end of join on another table--
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT Inf.InformationGUID AS InformationGUID
                        ,(ISNULL(Tax.Amount,0) + (Inf.CounterveilingDuty * (ISNULL([EntryRecord].StatisticValue,0) / ISNULL(NULLIF(EntryRecordSum.SumStatisticValue,0),1)))) AS Duty
                    FROM [Documentinformation] Inf 
                    LEFT JOIN [EntryRecordInformation] [EntryRecord] 
                    ON [EntryRecord].InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                    LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT InformationGUID, PartnerID, SUM(StatisticValue) AS SumStatisticValue
                        FROM [EntryRecordInformation] 
                        GROUP BY InformationGUID, PartnerID) EntryRecordSum
                        ON EntryRecordSum.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                        LEFT JOIN [EntryRecordTax] Tax 
                        ON Tax.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                            AND Tax.Code = '10'
                        GROUP BY Inf.InformationGUID
                            ,Tax.Amount
                            ,Inf.CounterveilingDuty
                            ,[EntryRecord].StatisticValue
                            ,EntryRecordSum.SumStatisticValue
                    ) DutyCalculate
                ON DutyCalculate.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                LEFT JOIN(
                    SELECT Inf.InformationGUID AS InformationGUID
                        ,(ISNULL(TaxInsurence.Amount,0) + (Inf.CounterveilingDuty * (ISNULL([EntryRecord].StatisticValue,0) / ISNULL(NULLIF(EntryRecordSum.SumStatisticValue,0),1))) 
                          + ISNULL(BorderTax.Amount,0) + ISNULL(CustomerTax.Amount,0) + ISNULL(OtherTax.Amount,0)
                          + ISNULL([EntryRecord].LocalPortExpenses,0) + ISNULL([EntryRecord].OtherLocalExpenses,0)
                          + ISNULL([EntryRecord].FreightAmount,0) + ISNULL([EntryRecord].InsuranceAmount,0)
                          + ISNULL([EntryRecord].TresspassingFeeAtTheBorder,0)) AS DeclarationPayments
                    FROM [Documentinformation] Inf 
                    LEFT JOIN [EntryRecordInformation] [EntryRecord] 
                    ON [EntryRecord].InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID AND [EntryRecord].PartnerID = Inf.PartnerId
                    LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT InformationGUID, PartnerID, SUM(StatisticValue) AS SumStatisticValue
                        FROM [EntryRecordInformation] 
                        GROUP BY InformationGUID, PartnerID) EntryRecordSum
                    ON EntryRecordSum.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                    LEFT JOIN [EntryRecordTax] TaxInsurence 
                    ON TaxInsurence.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID
                        AND TaxInsurence.Code = '10'
                    LEFT JOIN [EntryRecordTax] BorderTax 
                    ON BorderTax.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                        AND BorderTax.Code = '40'
                    LEFT JOIN [EntryRecordTax] CustomerTax 
                    ON CustomerTax.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                        AND CustomerTax.Code = '93'
                    LEFT JOIN [EntryRecordTax] OtherTax 
                    ON OtherTax.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                        AND OtherTax.Code = '89'
                    GROUP BY Inf.InformationGUID
                        ,TaxInsurence.Amount
                        ,BorderTax.Amount
                        ,CustomerTax.Amount
                        ,OtherTax.Amount
                        ,Inf.CounterveilingDuty
                        ,[EntryRecord].StatisticValue
                        ,EntryRecordSum.SumStatisticValue
                        ,[EntryRecord].LocalPortExpenses
                        ,[EntryRecord].OtherLocalExpenses
                        ,[EntryRecord].FreightAmount
                        ,[EntryRecord].InsuranceAmount
                        ,[EntryRecord].TresspassingFeeAtTheBorder
                    ) DeclarationPaymentsCalculate
                ON DeclarationPaymentsCalculate.InformationGUID = Inf.InformationGUID 
                GROUP BY Inf.InformationGUID
                    ,Inf.RegistryNumber
                    ,Inf.TaxIDOfTheDeclarant
                    ,Inf.TypeOfDocument
                    ,Inf.CustomerId
                    ,Inf.RelatedReference
                    ,Inf.TypeOfVehicleAtTheBorder
```

I don't face any error, but when i need to have  15 record in my view, because i have 15  id in all my table  i got  more than 63 ides, what should i manage to get rid of duplicate values?

Comment: check your table join condition. One of the join condition is returning multiple rows for one `ID`

Comment: You are right, but  i can't add condition which can reduce values, i mean i have same id-is  with  differenet DocumentDate so i can't use DISTINCT or MAX(DocumentDate ), what should i do in this case?

Comment: if you have multiple `DocumentDate` for one `ID`, which one do you want to show in the result ?

Comment: The latest date

Comment: then that is `max(DocumentDate)`

Comment: I tried this but in my table  i have  more than 100 record and  some of them have same date and guIds  as well

Comment: I have use this code Left JOIN table on table.guid=document.guid where  document.DocumentDate IN (select max(document.DocumentDate) from InformationDocument document)

Comment: But i  still can't get rid of  duplicate values

Comment: You have a complex query here with joins to multiple tables. Nobody else but you will be able to understand the query. Best is if you can simplify the problem with small sample data and post it as new question. You will get more helps.

Comment: in the mean time, you might want to take a look at `row_number() over() ` it might help your problem here

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

- one is to create a view that aggregates values based on group by, so something like

  SELECT t1.something, MAX(t1.somethingElse) as maxElse, MIN(t2.x) as minX
- the other is to use RANK (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql) which will return all of the duplicates, but also with rank columns that show their order in the partition. All you have to do then is add another filter:

  SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT with rank
  ) t 
  WHERE t.rank = 1

I think the second one is more correct and more clear, but it depends on your case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to do this in SQL Server.  It is really hard to say what the exact syntax is for your query, but you can use `top (1) with ties` instead of `select distinct`.

So:

```
select top (1) with ties . . .
from . . .
. . .
order by row_number() over (partition by <x> order by <y>)
-----------------------------------------^ you'll get one row for each value of this
------------------------------------------------------^ that row will be the first by this
```

This is really a "hack" solution for what you are doing.  If you expect fewer rows, you should fix the underlying query so it returns the rows that you want.  It is not clear where those rows come from, and your queries are way to complicated for anyone to figure out.

You will need to simplify, simplify the logic.  I would recommend starting with a query that just produces the rows you want.  Then add additional joins and columns and other logic to get the columns.